# Flutter Overflow Exception Despite SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `Textfield` and a List of `Chips` wrapped in a `Wrap` beneath.
When the `Textfield` is `active` and the keyboard pops up, I get an overflow exception at the bottom where the keyboard overlaps the wrapped `Chips`.

I figured putting the `Wrap` in a `SingleChildScrollView` would solve the problem, but for some reason it doesn't?
What am I missing here?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollableTest extends StatelessWidget {

final List<String> _items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 
                           'item6', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9', 'item10'];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Scroll Test'),
  ),
  body: new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
    child: new Center(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('Foo',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                new Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                ),
                new Text('bar',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                )
              ],
            )
          ),
          new Container(
            child:new TextField(
              autofocus: false,
              onChanged: (text) { },
            ),
          ),
          new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
              child: new Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                spacing: 5.0,
                runSpacing: 10.0,
                children: _items.map((a) => new Chip(label: new Text(a))).toList()
              ),
            )
          )
        ]
      )
    )
  )
);
}
}
```

Comment: could you provide all of your code so we can get it running to test?

Comment: @Mans I added the rest of the code, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: The code you provided is working fine for me. No overflow exceptions when I open the keyboard.  In the past I had a similar issue when I had nested `Scaffolds` . Is there a chance that's happening to you?

Comment: That is weird, I'm running literally the code above... And the keyboard does cover some of the Chips on your device?

Comment: Running the code this is what I get: https://imgur.com/a/FkhFwLl

Can you include a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Ah, ok. Can you increase the `padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),` to `200.0` or something so the keyboard will overlap the Chips and cause either the scrolling or the exception?

Comment: Will take a look tomorrow